# Не отображаются поля формы Django

Tags: python, django, формы

все представления есть, но почему-то не отображаются поля формы, она расположена в футере, то есть она присутствует на всех страницах сайта. также не могу понять что писать в

```
action = ""
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-4 mt-3', 'name': 'name', 'id': 'id_name', 'placeholder': 'Ваше имя:', 'required': ''}))
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=12, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-4 mt-3', 'name': 'phone', 'id': 'id_phone', 'maxlength': '12', 'placeholder': 'Номер телефона:', 'required': ''}))
```

views.py

```
def FormView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']

            recepients = ['any@gmail.com']
            send_mail(sender, phone, 'oany@gmail.com', recepients)
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'form': form})
```

base.html

```
            <form class="text-center p-5" action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                <h3 class="h4 mb-4">Есть вопросы?</h3>
                <p>Оставьте свой номер телефона и мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время</p>
                {{ form.sender }}
                {{ form.phone }}
                <small>Нажимая кнопку "Подтвердить" вы соглашаетесь с <a href="{% url 'policy' %}">Политикой конфиденциальности</a></small>
                <button class="btn btn-success rounded" type="submit">Подтвердить.</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: А вы не забываете во всех вьюхах всех страниц сайта создавать этот самый form?

Comment: она создана в base, в нем хефв шапка и футер, я подключаю ее на всех страницах

Comment: Вы используете в base переменную form. Вы уверены, что эта переменная существует? Если да, то откуда она по-вашему берётся?

Comment: во views.py же?

Comment: Ещё раз, вы прописали form во **всех** вьюхах, для которых вы ожидаете работающую форму? Вы в вопросе показали одну вьюху, но если речь о **всех** страницах, то одной вьюхи явно недостаточно, ведь одна вьюха отвечает за одну страницу, а не за все сразу.